# calculate the difference between start_time and current_time as well as end_time and current_time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs

Suppose,I have created a game and start time is "06/09/23 5:15:23 PM" and end time is "06/09/23 10:20:00 PM" . When user login before time like user login at "06/09/23 4:05:00 PM" then the  show the messsage to user that, game starts in 01h:10m:23s . if the user loggin at "06/09/23 8:10:00 PM" then show the message to user that, game closes in 02h:10m:23s. start time and end time will come from the server in unixtime string.

Comment: what is the format of `unixtime string`

Comment: @JaromandaX  see: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Comment: oh, so it's a unix timestamp ... not a "unixtime string"

Comment: so, to convert a unix timestamp to a javascript date, you multiply it by 1000 - the rest writes itself

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is, create a function that takes three props (say, currentTime, startTimeUnix, and endTimeUnix) to determine the time difference and  set the message based on the duration that you get.

```
function TimeDifferenceMessage({ currentTime, startTimeUnix, endTimeUnix }) {
    const startDateTime = moment.unix(startTimeUnix);
    const endDateTime = moment.unix(endTimeUnix);
    const currentDateTime = moment(currentTime, "DD/MM/YY h:mm:ss A");
    let message;
    if (currentDateTime.isBefore(startDateTime)) {
        const duration = moment.duration(startDateTime.diff(currentDateTime));
        message = `Game starts in ${whateverTimeYouMention}`;
    } else if (currentDateTime.isBetween(startDateTime, endDateTime)) {
        const duration = moment.duration(endDateTime.diff(currentDateTime));
        message = `Game closes in ...`;
    } else {
        message = "Game has ended.";
    }

    // return the message
}
```

Comment: It is JavaScript date library for parsing, manipulating, and formatting dates. You have tagged momentjs right while posting your question?

Comment: Sorry not you. @JaromandaX.  It is tagged when the question was posted?

Comment: Oh, right, that library that the author basically abandoned three years ago. I could've sworn it was called something else. Carry on